# Отключить перетаскивание не отключая клик

Tags: javascript, css

Не могу понять как отключить перетаскивание картинки не отключив при этом событие .onclick.

Comment: Перетаскивание чего и какой `onclick`?

Comment: Возможно так? При перетаскивании, событие клика может и не быть. `document.getElementById("imageId").onmousedown = function(){return false;}`

Answer (score 0):

Событие `ondragstart`

```html
<img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/1/ca/foto-makro-kartinka-zelenye.jpg" ondragstart="return false"/>
```